# How to use RefreshView event properly?

Tags: 7, views, ajax

I'm editing views rows via ajax request. After request I expected refresh of this view.

I've added custom ajax command:

```
  Drupal.ajax.prototype.commands.refresh_view = function(ajax, response, status) {
        var selector = Drupal.settings.my_module.refresh_selector;
        $(selector).triggerHandler('RefreshView');
    };
```

but nothing happends. I'm debugging this and have sure that selector is ok.
Maybe this issue is because that Drupal.views.instances is empty?

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

Solution is dead simple. 'Use Ajax' option in View settings must be enabled.